# Javascript Files loading in undesired order

Tags: javascript

I have two js files I pulled out of script elements. Everything was working until then. Now they're running in the wrong order.

```
// HTML
<script src="setup.js"></script>
<div id="fruit"></div>
<script src="display.js"></script>


//// NEW FILE: setup.js
window.fruit = {};    
window.fruit = "apples"; // this is populated with ajax not shown


//// NEW FILE: display.js
$('#fruit').text(window.fruit);
```

I get an error saying that window.fruit is undefined.

How can I tell the browser to wait to run the second file? I looked at defer, but it only works in IE10. I need IE 8 to work.

Comment: show your ajax call. ajax is async.

Comment: if window.fruit is populated via ajax, is it not just a case of the return having not been recieved when you use the window.fruit value? If you hardcode window.fruit, does it work then?

Comment: You use a script loader such as script.js  (http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) or require.js (http://requirejs.org/)

Answer (score 2):

In good old days before IE6 or below, the HTML parser will stop parsing the page, every time it encounters a `script` tag, downloads the js file, execute it and then continue with the parsing of remaining html. The reason for doing that in old browsers is that the js that you just downloaded can do anything, may be even change the location url there by triggering a request for new HTML page, there by wasting all other resources it downloaded till that point. To prevent that, old browsers defer the parsing until the script is completely downloaded and executed.

But soon browsers saw that as a limitation and started downloading JS resources in files. Any latest browser can download 8-10 resources without blocking.

You can use `<script src="myApp.js" defer>` to say that the browser can download the JS file without blocking the HTML parsing but once the download is done, it will execute the JS file. but as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer), there's only limited support for that in IE8 & 9.

Now that the browsers are downloading multiple resources in parallel, if one of your JS has a dependency on the previous one, things will go wild.

**So to avoid this, You can use a script loader like LABjs/requireJS/CurlJS to download
and wire your dependencies so that things execute in the order you
specify**

Answer (score 1):

Inside the second script try to check and dynamically include the first one, so that the variable is defined before the statement:

```
if(typeof window.fruit === 'undefined'){
    var requiredScript = document.createElement('script'); 
    requiredScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    requiredScript.src = 'http://yourdomain.com/setup.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(requiredScript, s);
}
$('#fruit').text(window.fruit);
```

...
btw why are you separating them into 2 scripts in the first place ...

Comment: Why are there 2 scripts? There's just a lot of stuff. In the setup I'm creating all these global variables. There's a get and set function for each. This is so I don't over-access the db. So if I already have relevant data I don't want to call the db again. Display is where I access the global variables and display their data to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LABJS](http://labjs.com/) or [RequreJS](http://requirejs.org/) plugins.

You can preserve order of loading your script like this in LABJS.

```
$LAB.setOptions({AlwaysPreserveOrder:true})
.script("setup.js")
.script("display.js")
```

**OR**

```
$LAB
.script("setup.js").wait()
.script("display.js")
```

display.js will wait untill setup.js is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use the **onload** of the first script to call for the second one?